# How to load js/css files in custom popup load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

In my project i am displaying a custom  pop up page like below by javascript which  has a form for user to fill,then I need to load some js files when pop up is loaded. 
how to load js files,plz help.

```
<html>
     <head>
           <script type='text/javascript' src='files/jsfiles/core.js'></script>
     </head>
     <body>
           <!- I need to call javascript function showUsers() from here->
          <input type='button' onclick='showUsers();' value='listUsers'>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your popup will be a simple alert like `alert('Popup message')` or a custom popup ?

Comment: No that is a custom popup which display a form for user to fill and submit.

Answer (score 3):

```
function loadScript(src) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.async = false;
    script.src = src;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
};

function loadStyle(src) {
    var style = document.createElement("link");
    style.rel = "stylesheet";
    style.href = src;
    document.head.appendChild(style);
};

function loadFiles() {
    var scriptsArray = ['src1url', 'src2url'.., 'scrnurl'];
    var csssArray = ['src1url', 'src2url'.., 'scrnurl'];
    for (var i = 0; i < scriptsArray.length; i++) {
        loadScript(scriptsArray[i]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < csssArray.length; i++) {
        loadStyle(csssArray[i]);
    }
};

function yoursubmitFcn(callback) {
    // your functionality here;
    callback();
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    // do your stuff
    yoursubmitFcn(loadFiles);
});
```

Also check: [Another short form](http://jsfiddle.net/14zmb49e/1/)

Comment: But i can't call any javascript function which is located inside my popup.

Comment: You can if you are not opening your popup in iFrame

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/howto)

Loading jQuery from CDN

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" 
media="screen" />
```

html

```
<a href="pop up page" onclick='openmsg_sent();' class="iframe open_pop">Sign in</a>
```

JS

```
    $('.open_pop').fancybox({
    });

    function openmsg_sent() {
    jQuery(".open_pop").trigger("click");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For better and consistent UI, you can use a div which you can display with fixed positioning on click of the button.
  I believe Alert wont be able to display css properties if am not wrong.

What you can do is, onclick of the button, in the JS, you can put your popup content into a div which is hidden initially and shown on click.

Hope this helps.